# Por que no puedo escribir sobre mi TextArea? JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Soy nuevo con javafx y tengo un error que no puedo resolver, tengo un textarea en el que quiero mostrar el texto del archivo que abra

**sample.fxml** MenuBar

```
<MenuBar fx:id="menu_bar" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="609.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <menus>
                        <Menu fx:id="menu_file" mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                            <items>
                                <MenuItem fx:id="item_open" text="Open" onAction="#onOpen" />
                                <MenuItem fx:id="item_save" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" onAction="#onSave" />
                                <MenuItem fx:id="item_saveAs" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save as" onAction="#onSaveas"/>
                                <MenuItem fx:id="item_new" mnemonicParsing="false" text="New" onAction="#onNew" />
                                <MenuItem fx:id="item_exit" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Salir" onAction="#onClose" />
                            </items>
                        </Menu>
```

**sample.fxml** TextArea

```
 <AnchorPane fx:id="panel_textArea" layoutX="27.0" layoutY="76.0" prefHeight="249.0" prefWidth="541.0">
            <children>
                <TextArea fx:id="text_area" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="528.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                <ScrollBar layoutX="304.0" layoutY="221.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="235.0" />
                <ScrollBar layoutX="520.0" layoutY="35.0" orientation="VERTICAL" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
```

**Controller.java**
Al momento de seleccionar "Open" se despliega un FilChooser, selecciono un archivo y con buffered reader leo ese achivo y cuando intento escribir las lineas leidas sobre el textarea sale el error

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    static TextArea text_area;

    @FXML
    private void onOpen()
    {


        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                new ExtensionFilter("Text Files", "*.txt"),
                new ExtensionFilter("PDF Files","*.pdf"),
                new ExtensionFilter("dat Files","*.dat")
                );
        String path_name = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage()).getPath();
        if (path_name != null) {
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path_name))) {
                String strCurrentLine;
                while ((strCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(strCurrentLine);
                    //text_area.appendText(strCurrentLine+"\n"); //-> aqui es donde pretendo agregar lo que lee mi bfr 
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1859)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.Controller.onOpen(Controller.java:36)
    ... 53 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Los campos anotados con `@FXML` no pueden tener los modificadores de acceso `static` ni `final` ya que no serán procesados por el `FXMLLoader` y por tanto "apuntarán" a `null` (a menos que manualmente tu le asignes un valor diferente).

Esto es lo que te está ocurriendo. Para solucionarlo simplemente elimina el modificador `static` de la declaración del `TextArea`:

```
@FXML
private TextArea text_area;
```

Comment: hice una chicanada para "resolverlo" y funciono, pero tu respuesta me ayuda a entender mejor como usar JavaFX, te agradezco infinitamente.